# My Python-MYSQL-program just sleeps forever after couple of hours running, but it's not a memory leak

Tags: python, mysql, linux, memory-leaks, mariadb

The following is a slightly censcored Python 3.7 program which apparently goes to sleep (0% cpu but still there according to htop) after a couple hours of running on Linux on my RaspberryPi. I've programmed it to react to STRG+C, after going to sleep, it still reacts to STRG+C, but I guess that still means that it's firmly asleep. It hasn't gained any memory since it started, still at 22MB,
also I've used a profiler to check that there aren't any memory leaks whatsoever.
The cursor is at the next line and the program just doesn't react anymore...

```
import mysql.connector, time, signal, requests
from mysql.connector import errorcode


USER = ...
PASSWORD = ...
HOST = ...
DATABASE = ...


RUNNING = True


def signal_handler(signum, frame):

    global RUNNING

    signal.signal(signum, signal.SIG_IGN) # ignore additional signals
    print('Received shutdown signal')
    print('Treating remaining players as if they just went offline...')
    RUNNING = False


def time_string(timestamp, forString = False, brackets = False):

    hours = int((timestamp // 3600 + (0 if forString else 2)) % 24)
    minutes = int(timestamp // 60 % 60)
    seconds = int(timestamp % 60)

    shours = ('0' if hours < 10 else '') + str(hours)
    sminutes = ('0' if minutes < 10 else '') + str(minutes)
    sseconds = ('0' if seconds < 10 else '') + str(seconds)

    ret = shours+':'+sminutes+':'+sseconds

    if brackets:
        ret = '['+ret+']'

    return ret


def main():

    global USER, PASSWORD, HOST, DATABASE

    start_timestamp = None
    end_timestamp = None

    registeredWhen = dict()
    startedOnline = dict()
    startedPlaying = dict()


    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user=USER, password=PASSWORD, host=HOST, database=DATABASE)
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            print("Database does not exist")
        else:
            print(err)
        conn.close()
        return


    conn.autocommit = True
    cursor = conn.cursor(prepared=True)


    cursor.execute(
        """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recording_periods(
            player TEXT,
            start INTEGER,
            end INTEGER
        )
        """
    )
    cursor.execute(
        """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS online_periods(
            player TEXT,
            start INTEGER,
            end INTEGER
        )
        """
    )
    cursor.execute(
        """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS playing_periods(
            player TEXT,
            start INTEGER,
            end INTEGER
        )
        """
    )
    cursor.execute(
        """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players_to_record(
            player TEXT
        )
        """
    )

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

    last_timestamp = time.time()-1
    timestamp = last_timestamp

    start_timestamp = None
    end_timestamp = None

    while RUNNING or [] != [x for x in startedOnline if startedOnline[x] != None]  or [] != [x for x in startedPlaying if startedPlaying[x] != None]:

        timestamp = int(time.time())
        while timestamp == last_timestamp:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            timestamp = int(time.time())


        cursor.execute("""SELECT player FROM players_to_record""")
        nplayers = set([x[0].decode().lower() for x in cursor.fetchall()])

        added = set([player for player in nplayers if player not in registeredWhen])
        removed = set([player for player in registeredWhen if player not in nplayers])

        for player in added:
            print('Registered player '+player)

            registeredWhen[player] = timestamp
            startedOnline[player] = None
            startedPlaying[player] = None

        info = []
        for player in removed:
            print('Unregistered player '+player)

            info.append((player, registeredWhen[player], end_timestamp))

            registeredWhen.pop(player)
            startedOnline.pop(player)
            startedPlaying.pop(player)

        cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO recording_periods VALUES (?, ?, ?)""", info)

        url = 'https://lichess.org/api/users/status?ids='
        for player in registeredWhen:
            url = url + player +','
        url = url[:-1]

        try:
            resp = requests.get(url)
            data = resp.json()
            resp.close()

            ts = time_string(timestamp, brackets=True)
            tsnb = time_string(timestamp, brackets=False)
            ronline = []
            rplaying = []
            for user in data:

                name_id = user['id']
                name = user['name']

                online = 'online' in user and user['online']
                playing = 'playing' in user and user['playing']

                if start_timestamp == None:
                    start_timestamp = timestamp
                end_timestamp = timestamp

                if startedOnline[name_id] == None and online and RUNNING:
                    startedOnline[name_id] = timestamp
                    print(ts,name,'went online')
                elif startedOnline[name_id] != None and ((not online) or not RUNNING):
                    ronline.append((name_id, startedOnline[name_id], timestamp))
                    st = time_string(startedOnline[name_id])
                    dt = time_string(timestamp - startedOnline[name_id], forString=True)
                    print(ts,name,'went offline, was online from',st,'to',tsnb,'for',dt)
                    startedOnline[name_id] = None

                if startedPlaying[name_id] == None and playing and RUNNING:
                    startedPlaying[name_id] = timestamp
                    print(ts,name,'started playing')
                elif startedPlaying[name_id] != None and ((not playing) or not RUNNING):
                    rplaying.append((name_id, startedPlaying[name_id], timestamp))
                    st = time_string(startedPlaying[name_id])
                    dt = time_string(timestamp - startedPlaying[name_id], forString=True)
                    print(ts,name,'stopped playing, was playing from',st,'to',tsnb,'for',dt)
                    startedPlaying[name_id] = None

            cursor.executemany("""
                        INSERT INTO online_periods
                        VALUES(?, ?, ?)
                        """, ronline
                        )
            cursor.executemany("""
                        INSERT INTO playing_periods
                        VALUES(?, ?, ?)
                        """, rplaying
                        )


        except Exception as ex:
            template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
            message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
            print (message)
            time.sleep(1)

    st = time_string(start_timestamp)
    et = time_string(end_timestamp)
    dt = time_string(end_timestamp - start_timestamp, forString=True)
    print('Recorded from',st,'to',et,'for',dt)
    print('Writing recording periods to the database...')

    cursor.executemany("""
                        INSERT INTO recording_periods
                        VALUES(?, ?, ?)
                        """, [(player, registeredWhen[player], end_timestamp) for player in registeredWhen]
                        )
    print('Committing ...')
    conn.commit()
    print('Closing database connection...')
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    print('Exit program...')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Could it be the terminal? That it's not suited for running for long hours?
But I'd like to use a terminal.

Since my program prints when encountering an error but the terminal doesn't print any error messages,
my guess would be that it's either stuck in the database queries or the requests at Lichess.org.
Our router/Lichess restart from time to time, the databaseServer is up non-stop and has no other program accessing it (which might block the programs query). It's a MariaDB running on the same Raspberry Pi.

I've no idea how and why it gets stuck, please tell me that you guys do!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out now,

it's because there's no timeout in requests.get() be default.
When the router restarts while your requests.get() is running, it'll just wait forever.
Fixed it by adding timeout=10. What were the creators of that library thinking??